# Why Frida (Inject) doesn't hook getPackageInfo and other methods?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reverse-engineering, frida

I am having problems creating a script in JavaScript for Frida.
I want to hook the `getPackageInfo` method in order to log when it is called in the console, i have overloaded the old and the new version of it using this code:

```
    jPM = Java.use('android.content.pm.PackageManager');
    jPM.getPackageInfo.overload('java.lang.String','int').implementation=(pname,f)=>{
        console.warn("Called => getPackageInfo ("+f+")");
        return jPM.getPackageInfo.call(this,pname,f);
    }
    jPM.getPackageInfo.overload('android.content.pm.VersionedPackage','int').implementation=(vp,f)=>{
        console.warn("Called => getPackageInfo [API level 33] ("+f+")");
        return jPM.getPackageInfo.call(this,vp,f);
    }
```

When i try to run the script I don't get any error, but I don't get any log in the console.
I am sure that the method that is being called is the first, because it's signature is this in smali:

`Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;->getPackageInfo(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;`

I can't understand what am I doing wrong, if i use the same code to hook other methods it works. Please help me

Comment: You could simply have edit your old question and modify it to this question. Also the link I had posted may be of use to others as it in the end contained the solution you describe in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by using `android.app.ApplicationPackageManager` instead of `android.content.pm.PackageManager`.

Thanks to @Robert for giving me the link to this example code: https://codeshare.frida.re/@limyout/test/

Comment: You should edit your answer and include the link I had posted on your last now deleted question as it contained the solution you have posted in this answer.

Comment: @Robert yes sorry